# HoloViews Dataset transform to QuadMesh

Tags: python, numpy, holoviews, holoviz

### Case description

I have a set of spectral maps (intensity dependent on time and frequency) for a set of detectors which can be fit into a 3D array `BlockDataset` of size `M x N x K` (here: `M` = number of frequencies, `N` number of time steps and `K` is the number of detectors).
The `M` frequencies are log-spaced and the `K` detectors are normally indexed by a tuple consiting of 2 angles but for brevity I'm considering only one angle. The `N` time values are equidistant.

Creating a HoloViews dataset from `BlockDataset` with appropriate value arrays for all of the dimensions is possible, but requires me to switch from a simple `hv.Image` display to a `hv.QuadMesh` display.

### Problem description

If the dataset is created with actual angle values, instead of just detector numbers, a conversion to a `HoloMap` fails with the following error:

```
DataError: The shape of the intensity value array does not match the expected dimensionality indicated by the key dimensions. Expected 2-D array, found 3-D array.
```

If detector numbers (integers) are used instead of angles (floating point numbers) there's no problem.

### Code

```py
timeDim = hv.Dimension("time", label="Time", unit="sec", values=times)
freqDim = hv.Dimension("frequency", label = "Angular frequency", unit="$\\frac{rad}{s}", values=omega)
polarAngleDim = hv.Dimension("angle", label=" $\varphi$", unit="rad", values=angles[:,0])
intensityDim = hv.Dimension("intensity", label="Intensity $\\frac{d^2 W}{d\Omega d\omega}(t,\vartheta,\varphi)", unit="J/(s srad)")

hvDatasetNatural = hv.Dataset((times, angles[:,0], omega, BlockDataset.transpose()), [timeDim, polarAngleDim, freqDim], intensityDim)
subset = hvDatasetNatural.select( angle=list(angles[selectedIndices,0]) )
img = subset.to( new_type=hv.QuadMesh, kdims=[timeDim, freqDim])
```

The selection of a `subset` appears to work properly, but neither the conversion of the subset, nor of the entire dataset to `QuadMesh` works.
Note again: `times` are lin-spaced float values, `angles` are nonlinearly spaced floats and `omega` are log-spaced float values.

### Query

1. What may be the problem here? I.e., why doesn't `.to()` work on the dataset when 2 of the 3 dimensions are non-equidistant, non-integer values but it works well if only `omega` is kept non-equidistant?

I can construct a `QuadMesh` for a specific angle using `hv.QuadMesh( (...), kdim=[..])` and hence essentially unwrapping the original object.

2. (an extra) Why does an aggregation along the, e.g., time dimension using `subset.reduce(timeDim, np.sum)` work, but `subset.reduce(timeDim, np.trapz)` fails with:

```
DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format. GridInterface raised following error:

 GridInterface interface requires at least one value dimension.
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask], and try to simplify your example and provide setup code as a [mre]. Please only ask one question at a time - you’re welcome to post more than one question, but tailor your setup and explanation to only include the information and code for each. Thanks!

Comment: Right; tough to follow without complete, runnable code, ideally boiled down to a very specific issue. The HoloViews community typically discusses such issues at  https://discourse.holoviz.org/c/holoviews/6 ...